# in ecilpse R.java file under gen is not gernating

Tags: android, eclipse

i probably do some manuplication with eclipse ,and now in ecilpse R.java file under gen is not   gernating ??? how to resolved this

Comment: Check that the names of your resources (/res folder) are named correctly (small letters, letters and underscore only)

Comment: Check for errors also clean project and rebuild.

Comment: @Mohamed_AbdAllah   under res folder there are many other folder and file. which i have to look at?

Comment: @zapl  i already done that

Comment: All your resource names (Strings, layouts, drawables, ...)

Comment: use the steps that i have given..

Comment: plz check the layout & other xml files. if something wrong in any of the xml file R.java wont generated ...& for tht clean & build project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely there is an error in one of your xml files. Look for errors in the log output. Something like an unclosed tag, illegal name or so?

Answer (score 0):

use these steps to solve your problem..

**1)** Open your android sdk manager.

**2)** There you will see Android build tools upadate or install.

**3)** After installing/updating.

**4)** Restart Eclipse this will solve the problem..

enjoy..

Comment: okay i will go for your method

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the Project and create a new project .

Answer (score 0):

Copy an old R.java file from any other project, it will recreate itself!!!

Answer (score 0):

This error is basically generated because of xml files.
Try to build your project again,
if nothing happens then,

Do one thing delete your layout folder and create it again.
That will generate the new hexa values for objects, you have used in layout, and rebuild your gen folder automatically.

Then your project will not show any R.java error.